# avatar is not displaying in custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have created a custom profile page in which I want to show profile picture. I use the below code to show the avatar:

```
<div class="activity-avatar">   
   <a href="<?php bp_activity_user_link(); ?>"><?php bp_activity_avatar(); ?></a>
</div>

<?php bp_displayed_user_avatar( 'type=full' ); ?>
<?php global $userdata; get_currentuserinfo();
echo get_avatar($userdata->ID, 46 ); ?>
```

But I don't get the avatar of user. If I use `<?php bp_activity_avatar(); ?>` outside of the main `<div>` then it shows the avatar of the last updated profile picture, not of the current user. But I don't get Avatar at the needed position. How can I get avatar at any position in template? I use bootstrap classes, could the problem occur from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$userid = bp_loggedin_user_id();
echo bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $userid) );
```

You don't explain the context of your custom profile page, so `$userid` might need to be changed to `$userid = bp_displayed_user_id()` or however you determine the user id for a page view.

Comment: what is 'item_id' here ?

Comment: It's work but height and width are so small, can I give it as arguments?

Comment: Yes, there are several parameters available. See http://hookr.io/functions/bp_core_fetch_avatar/

Comment: It works fine , Now I want to provide change avatar  option. I used rt-media plugin in my project so I used the short code  <?php echo do_shortcode('[rtmedia_uploader]'); ?> to provide media uploading option . but at front-end I click on upload button but It is not showing browse option. So I can't upload any media. Is there any code option by which I can provide user to change avatar and upload media option